# How can I add a computed field using an arbitrary function with Mongo aggregate framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using [MongoDB's Aggregate Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). I have an existing field in each of my documents:

```
time: Date
```

And I wish create a new field `timeBlock` based on a simple funcion:

```
var dateToTimeBlock = function(dateString, timeBlock){
    return new Date(dateString).valueOf() / timeBlock 
}
```

I understand that [$group can add fields](http://www.slideshare.net/cwestin63/mongodbs-new-aggregation-framework), but the functions used to calculate those fields seems to be built into mongo, eg, `$avg`, `$add`, etc. **Is it possible to generate a computed value based on an arbitrary field?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can compute fields using aggregation framework. If you want to use native JavaScript functions (like `valueOf` on `Date` object) you will have to use [Map-Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/).

Although, aggregation framework is not as flexible as Map-Reduce, in most cases it will be significantly faster. If performance is critical I would precalculate those values and use a simple query instead.

If you want to use aggregation, you can simplify it by converting the Date into an integer or add a new field in the document that's an integer. Then you can than do your calculations easily with [$divide](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/#exp._S_divide).

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    { $project : { dateToTime: { $divide : [ "$timeInt", timeBlock ] }}}
]);
```

Or if `timeBlock` is a field in the same document you can do it like this:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    { $project : { dateToTime: { $divide : [ "$timeInt", "$timeBlock" ] }}}
]);
```